# Cakephp javascript onclick submit function on view

Tags: php, javascript, dom, cakephp

I'm trying to use Javascript's onclick submit function on the view file of Cakephp site and it doesn't seem to do anything when it's clicked...

Any suggestions?

```
<?php echo $form->submit('  Preview  ', array('label'=>false,'name'=>'submit','id'=>'print_log')); ?>
<a id="print_log" href="#" onclick="this.form.submit()" name="submit">
<?php echo $html->image("btn_preview.jpg",array("alt" => "Preview")); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: I've actually used button function with style background and url with image path and it worked!

Below is my answer:

    <button style="border: medium none; background: url('/img/btn_preview.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0pt 0pt transparent; height: 26px; width: 85px; cursor: pointer;" type="submit"></button>

Strange that Cakephp does not allow onclick function to work with form properly when submitting through Javascript. Anyways, job done!

Comment: You might as well add this as an answer and possibly also accept @lxa 's answer

Answer (score 1):

[`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48250443) is not a form element (while [`<input>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) or [`<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-34812697) are), therefore `this.form` is undefined for it. 
It has nothing to do with CakePHP.